# add-to-list, replace

Tags: org-agenda

Is there any way to overwrite the "y" entry?

Every time when I evaluate this, it gets added as a new item on the list.

It makes it hard find an expression that works, when I can't replace the items on the list, without redefining the whole list again;)

```el
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
    `("y"                     
      "f.emacs t.todo retry"  
      agenda                   ;type
      ""                       ;match - empty string for agenda type
      ((org-agenda-files '("/foo/bar.hukarz"))
       (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done))
       (org-agenda-span 'week)
       (org-deadline-warning-days 5)
       (org-super-agenda-groups '((:auto-category t :time-grid t))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One, relatively manual but relatively safe, way to do this is to define a symbol with the value of the element that you want to add:

```el
(setq x '("y" ....))
```

The name of the symbol allows you to manipulate things much more easily. You can add it to the list, test and if you decide you need to change it, delete it from the list and redefine it differently before going back through the whole cycle again:

```el
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-cmmands x)
;;; test
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands (delete x org-agenda-custom-commands))
(setq x '("y" ....))
;;; lather, rinse, repeat
```

I find that convenient, and I get direct confirmation since both `add-to-list` and `delete` return the resulting list: I can eyeball it and make sure that things are as they should be.

You could automate the above, but automated solutions tend to lose that feedback.

---

If you have a list already constructed and you want to delete an element that you don't have a handle on (e.g. you don't have a variable that is set to this element as above), you could do something like this:

```el
;; construct a list to play with - in the scenario, this is something 
;; that exists already, but for the sake of the example
;; I construct it explicitly here
 
(setq some-list '((a b c) (d e f) (g h i) (j k l)))

;; suppose you want to delete the third element, i.e. (g h i)
;; - you can get this element with (nth 2 some-list) 
;; - note that `nth' counts from 0.

(nth 2 some-list) ;; ---> (g h i)

;; You can then call `delete' to make you a new list with that
;; element deleted and assign it back to `some-list'
(setq some-list (delete (nth 2 some-list) some-list)) 
   ;; ---> ((a b c) (d e f) (j k l))
```

So you get the element in this case by using the index of the element in the list. If the list is short, it's easy to count elements.

You could also get a handle using `assoc':

```el
;; Assume we are starting with the initial list again (i.e. containing (g h i)

(assoc 'g some-list) ;; ---> (g h i)

(setq some-list (delete (assoc 'g some-list) some-list))
    ;; ---> (a b c) (d e f) (j k l))
```

Here you get the element by *searching* the list for the element of interest.

If you have a preexisting list and you want to delete an element from it, one or the other of these methods might be useful. The important thing is the *pattern*: you somehow get the element and then you use `delete` with that element on the original list. That returns a new list which you assign back to the list variable.

Comment: Fixed a bug in the code: `delete` returns the modified list which has to be saved back to the original list in order to undo the change.

Comment: This does not work for me; i only get Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp org-agenda-custom-commands)

Comment: Another bug: no quote on `org-agenda-custom-commands` in the `delete` form. Sorry about that: fixed.

Comment: Thank you; that works;)

Comment: I do experience though, that when I forget to delete an entry and I accidentally add it, that I have trouble deleting it. I'm thinking maybe I should rather go for a solution that overwrites the current entry, some kind of ID, so that I don't have to worry about it;)

Comment: Not sure I understand the scenario you are describing - maybe give an example (and perhaps in a new question?)  I added another couple of methods that *might* address your concern but I'm not sure.

Comment: I was thinking more like a Map, instead of a List, where, if I add an object with the same identifier, it would get overwritten. That way, I would not have to worry about deleting the object in the list;)

Comment: OK - that would be a new question.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but if I look at my original question, it's "Is there any way to overwrite the 'y' entry?" If you say so, I'll create a new question;)

Comment: You are talking about a list in your question: the only way to modify it is to delete the entry you don't want and add a new entry (well, perhaps not the only way: you could do surgery on the entry, but that is rather complicated). You said "... a Map, instead of a List" - now, I don't know what a Map is in this case (maybe a hash table of some sort?) but whatever it is, it is not a list: so yes, it is a different question.